# fibonacci print out issue in c++

Tags: c++, fibonacci

I was trying to run the fib.exe by using this command "fib 12" so it can directly print out the result in this format:
http://pastebin.com/ytR92i8f

But with my code compiled, for instance, if I use 12 to test my program, it won' t read any number and show the result in this command "fib xx" but it will run the program and let you type the number you want in the next line  and then print out the result...

I have attached the link to my main.cpp below as reference.

main.cpp :      http://pastebin.com/fhUAkNQR

Because main.c can not be modify so I can only use one function to get it works.
Right now I already have the correct result.

```
void fibonacci(int max)
{

do
{
  std::cin >> max;
} 
while(max < 2 && max > 46);  

std::cout << "           Fibonacci        Fibonacci" << std::endl;
std::cout << " N           number          quotient" << std::endl;
std::cout << "-------------------------------------" << std::endl;
std::cout << " 0             0                  N/A" << std::endl;
std::cout << " 1             1                  N/A" << std::endl;

int count = max;
int fib1 = 0, fib2 = 1;

for (int i = 2; i <= count; i++)
{
  int next = fib1 + fib2;

  // Add statements to print here...
  std::cout << std::setw(2) << i;
  std::cout << std::setw(14) << next;
  std::cout << std::setw(21) << std::setprecision(17) << std::showpoint;
  std::cout << static_cast<double>(next) / fib2 << std::endl;
  std::cout.unsetf(std::ios_base::showpoint);

  fib1 = fib2;
  fib2 = next;
}


return;
```

}

Comment: Can you explain the `while` loop condition?

Comment: while the input number is both greater than 2 and less than 46, end while？

Comment: No. That's not what you have. Try "while the input number is both *less than* 2 and *greater than* 46, end while". Now I'm no Fields Medal winner but I can't think of an integer that satisfies that condition.

Comment: My bad..yes I was going to say "is both less than 2 and greater than 46", and I have to type the number I want to test at the second line after the command

Comment: So what is the point of the while loop if the condition is always false?

Comment: well I just tried   while(1)
    if(max == 1)
       return;
    else if (max > 1 && max <= 46)
 break;
      input++;
      and now it works properly by just type the number x in the command the "fib xx" , I think now I should deal with the infinite loop  when I test with the number greater than 46.

Comment: I think I got what I want. Thanks for remind me the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's and example. Problems like the Fibonacci are better dealt with recursion. I see that with your do while loops you are trying to use some sort of recursion but it's not really working

```
int fibonacci(int x)
{
    if (x == 0)
        return 0;

    if (x == 1)
        return 1;

    return fibonacci(x-1)+fib(x-2);
}
```

This basically does all you've typed in your main, just supply x and enjoy. Recursion is a difficult concept but once you've got the idea it can preform very effectively but it's pretty limited in my opinion.